# Filter by a calculated state and map that state

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to retrieve and filter instances of an entity persisted in a database. To achive that, I need to use a calculated field State. The user can select to filter by state1, state2, ... state5 or any combination thereof. The State property is not in the table, it is calculated in the query, but I need this value outside of the query.

```
public class EntityData
{
    ... //some properties I need to calculate state
}

public class Entity
{
    public EntityStateEnum State { get; set; }
    ... //other properties
}

IQueryable<EntityData> data = dbContext.EntityDbSet
    .Where( !filterByState1 || //complex logic expression to calculate and filter by state1 )
    .Where( !filterByState2 || //complex logic expression to calculate and filter by state2 )
    .Where( ... //more states and other filter criteria)

IEnumerable<Entity> result = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Entity>>(data);
```

I would like to map the calculated state of `EntityData` with the `State` property of `Entity`.
How could I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is State a complex/costly calculation and you want cache the calculated state value for internal processing? Perhaps you are looking for something like `.Select(entity => new { entity, State = entity.CalculateState() })` or `.Select(entity => new EntityState { Property1 = entity.Property1, Property2 = entity.Property2, State = entity.CalculateState() })`.

Comment: As for the `.Where()` conditions: If this is an `IQueryable<>` that is going to be translated to a SQL query, it is much more efficient to dynamically include or exclude the `.Where()` conditions than to include an OR as part of the condition. Better is something like `var data = dbContext.EntityDbSet; if (filterByState1) { data = data.Where(...); } if (filterByState2) { data = data.Where(...); } ...`. The reason is that OR conditions are difficult or impossible for the query engine to optimize.

Comment: The state is actually a complex calculation. I tried to simplify the question, but there are also many possible states and the user can select any combination of them. I need the calculated state of each element to be assigned to the State property of the Entity.

Comment: Why is `State` a property of another class, instead of a (computed) property of `EntityData`? How is the `State` property related to state1,state2,...? I think you've left out too much code.

Comment: EntityData is a repository class that maps to the database table and is used by the ORM framework (EF). Entity is a class of the model that is used for business logic. EntityData doesn't have the property State because the database table doesn't have the State field.